# Without changing the shape of the figure, how I can decrease the size?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{figure}
{   
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.00]
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (0.5,1.3) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (0.0,0) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (1,0) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (2.2,0.25) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (1.65,1.05) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (1.45,2.15) {};


\draw (0.7,1.30) node{$C$};
\draw (0.5,1.30) node{.};
\draw (-0.1,-0.10) node{$A$};
\draw (0.183,0.07) node{\footnotesize{$\alpha$}};
\draw (0.183,0.37) node{\footnotesize{$\gamma$}};
\draw (0.82,0.29) node{\footnotesize{$\beta$}};


\draw (0.5,0.70) node {$O$};

\draw (0,0) node{.};
\draw (1.1,0) node{$B$};
\draw (1,0) node{.};

\draw (0,0)--(0.50,0.57);
\draw (-0.002,-0.0)--(0.50,1.31);
\draw (1.005,0)--(0.50,1.31);


\draw (1,0)--(0.50,0.57);
\draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw [thick]( 0.12 , 0.0 )-- ( 0.119 , 0.0155 )-- ( 0.118 , 0.0218 )-- ( 0.117 , 0.0267 )-- ( 0.116 , 0.0307 )-- ( 0.115 , 0.0343 )-- ( 0.114 , 0.0375 )-- ( 0.113 , 0.0404 )-- ( 0.112 , 0.0431 )-- ( 0.111 , 0.0456 )-- ( 0.11 , 0.048 )-- ( 0.109 , 0.0502 )-- ( 0.108 , 0.0523 )-- ( 0.107 , 0.0543 )-- ( 0.106 , 0.0562 )-- ( 0.105 , 0.0581 )-- ( 0.104 , 0.0599 )-- ( 0.103 , 0.0616 )-- ( 0.102 , 0.0632 )-- ( 0.101 , 0.0648 )-- ( 0.1 , 0.0663 )-- ( 0.099 , 0.0678 )-- ( 0.098 , 0.0693 )-- ( 0.097 , 0.0706 )-- ( 0.096 , 0.072 )-- ( 0.095 , 0.0733 )-- ( 0.094 , 0.0746 )-- ( 0.093 , 0.0758 )-- ( 0.092 , 0.077 )-- ( 0.091 , 0.0782 )-- ( 0.09 , 0.0794 )-- ( 0.089 , 0.0805 )-- ( 0.088 , 0.0816 )-- ( 0.087 , 0.0826 )-- ( 0.086 , 0.0837 )-- ( 0.085 , 0.0847 )-- ( 0.084 , 0.0857 )-- ( 0.083 , 0.0867 )-- ( 0.082 , 0.0876 )-- ( 0.081 , 0.0885 )-- ( 0.08 , 0.0894 )-- ( 0.079 , 0.0903 )-- ( 0.078 , 0.0912 )-- ( 0.077 , 0.092 )-- ( 0.076 , 0.0929 )-- ( 0.075 , 0.0937 )-- ( 0.074 , 0.0945 )-- ( 0.073 , 0.0952 )-- ( 0.072 , 0.096 
)-- ( 0.071 , 0.0967 )-- ( 0.07 , 0.0975 )-- ( 0.069 , 0.0982 );

\draw [thick]( 0.635 , 0.4224 )-- ( 0.63 , 0.418 )-- ( 0.625 , 0.4139 )-- ( 0.62 , 0.41 )-- ( 0.615 , 0.4064 )-- ( 0.61 , 0.403 )-- ( 0.605 , 0.3998 )-- ( 0.6 , 0.3968 )-- ( 0.595 , 0.394 )-- ( 0.59 , 0.3914 )-- ( 0.585 , 0.389 )-- ( 0.58 , 0.3867 )-- ( 0.575 , 0.3846 )-- ( 0.57 , 0.3827 )-- ( 0.565 , 0.3809 )-- ( 0.56 , 0.3792 )-- ( 0.555 , 0.3777 )-- ( 0.55 , 0.3764 )-- ( 0.545 , 0.3751 )-- ( 0.54 , 0.374 )-- ( 0.535 , 0.3731 )-- ( 0.53 , 0.3723 )-- ( 0.525 , 0.3716 )-- ( 0.52 , 0.371 )-- ( 0.515 , 0.3706 )-- ( 0.51 , 0.3703 )-- ( 0.505 , 0.3701 )-- ( 0.5 , 0.37 )-- ( 0.495 , 0.3701 )-- ( 0.49 , 0.3703 )-- ( 0.485 , 0.3706 )-- ( 0.48 , 0.371 )-- ( 0.475 , 0.3716 )-- ( 0.47 , 0.3723 )-- ( 0.465 , 0.3731 )-- ( 0.46 , 0.374 )-- ( 0.455 , 0.3751 )-- ( 0.45 , 0.3764 )-- ( 0.445 , 0.3777 )-- ( 0.44 , 0.3792 )-- ( 0.435 , 0.3809 )-- ( 0.43 , 0.3827 )-- ( 0.425 , 0.3846 )-- ( 0.42 , 0.3867 )-- ( 0.415 , 0.389 )-- ( 0.41 , 0.3914 )-- ( 0.405 , 0.394 )-- ( 0.4 , 0.3968 )-- ( 0.395 , 0.3998 )-- ( 0.39 , 0.403 )-- ( 0.
385 , 0.4064 )-- ( 0.38 , 0.41 )-- ( 0.375 , 0.4139 )-- ( 0.37 , 0.418 );


\draw( 0.09 , 0.265141 )-- ( 0.1 , 0.261534 )-- ( 0.11 , 0.257488 )-- ( 0.12 , 0.252982 )-- ( 0.13 , 0.247992 )-- ( 0.14 , 0.242487 )-- ( 0.15 , 0.236432 )-- ( 0.16 , 0.229783 )-- ( 0.17 , 0.222486 )-- ( 0.18 , 0.214476 )-- ( 0.19 , 0.20567 );

\draw( 0.83 , 0.189737 )-- ( 0.84 , 0.203224 )-- ( 0.85 , 0.215407 )-- ( 0.86 , 0.226495 )-- ( 0.87 , 0.236643 )-- ( 0.88 , 0.245967 )-- ( 0.89 , 0.254558 )-- ( 0.9 , 0.262488 )-- ( 0.91 , 0.269815 );
\draw (0.52,0.32) node{\footnotesize{$\pi$-$2\alpha$}};

\draw (-.4,-0.8) node{$C_1$};
\draw (1.5,-0.8) node{$C_2$};
\draw (0.52,-0.72) node{$P$};
\draw (-.25,0.80) node{$R$};
\draw (1.25,0.80) node{$Q$};

\draw (0.40,2.15) node{$C_3$};
\draw[dotted](0.71,2.02)--(1.45,2.15)--(2.02,1.70)--(1.65,1.05)--(2.41,0.97)--(2.2,0.25)--(1.7,-0.30)--(1,0)--(0.50,-0.55)--(0,0)--(-0.0,0.75)--(0.5,1.30)--(0.71,2.02);
\draw[dotted](0.5,1.30)--(1.00,0.75)--(1.65,1.05);

\draw[dotted] (1.00,0.75)--(1,0);



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}
\caption{}
\label{figcir}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally adjusting the scale factor which you have set as `scale=2.00` would do the job.  However in this case you have nodes of fixed minimum size, and also text. So in that case you can use `scalebox`.  Here is what your figure looks like with a scale of factor `0.75`, `0.50`:

[image]

Unfortunately this method also scales the text. I am not sure that there is an easy automated way to adjust this figure without going back to the s/w that you used to generate it in the first place.

I don't think is very difficult of a figure to draw yourself directly with `tikz`, but there is a learning curve involved. If you are doing many of these different figures than I would recommend you learn `tikz` as then you would have much more control over the figure.

### Notes:

- With this method you will need to place the `scalebox{}{}` in the floating environment, not the `tikzpicture`.

---

The only other option I can think of is to adjust the `minimum size` of the circles based on the scale factor, but then the output gets cluttered as there is too much information:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MinSize}{3*\Scale/2}
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, red] at (0.5,1.3) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, blue] at (0.0,0) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, brown] at (1,0) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, magenta] at (2.2,0.25) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, violet] at (1.65,1.05) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, green] at (1.45,2.15) {};
```

Here is the output with `scale` changed from 2.00, to 1.5, and 1.0 (colors added so I could trace the output with the code):

[image]

As you can see the figure is quite cluttered so can't really get much of a scaling this way.

---

### Code: Using `\scalebox` scaling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyPic}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.00]
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (0.5,1.3) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (0.0,0) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (1,0) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (2.2,0.25) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (1.65,1.05) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (1.45,2.15) {};


\draw (0.7,1.30) node{$C$};
\draw (0.5,1.30) node{.};
\draw (-0.1,-0.10) node{$A$};
\draw (0.183,0.07) node{\footnotesize{$\alpha$}};
\draw (0.183,0.37) node{\footnotesize{$\gamma$}};
\draw (0.82,0.29) node{\footnotesize{$\beta$}};


\draw (0.5,0.70) node {$O$};

\draw (0,0) node{.};
\draw (1.1,0) node{$B$};
\draw (1,0) node{.};

\draw (0,0)--(0.50,0.57);
\draw (-0.002,-0.0)--(0.50,1.31);
\draw (1.005,0)--(0.50,1.31);


\draw (1,0)--(0.50,0.57);
\draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw [thick]( 0.12 , 0.0 )-- ( 0.119 , 0.0155 )-- ( 0.118 , 0.0218 )-- ( 0.117 , 0.0267 )-- ( 0.116 , 0.0307 )-- ( 0.115 , 0.0343 )-- ( 0.114 , 0.0375 )-- ( 0.113 , 0.0404 )-- ( 0.112 , 0.0431 )-- ( 0.111 , 0.0456 )-- ( 0.11 , 0.048 )-- ( 0.109 , 0.0502 )-- ( 0.108 , 0.0523 )-- ( 0.107 , 0.0543 )-- ( 0.106 , 0.0562 )-- ( 0.105 , 0.0581 )-- ( 0.104 , 0.0599 )-- ( 0.103 , 0.0616 )-- ( 0.102 , 0.0632 )-- ( 0.101 , 0.0648 )-- ( 0.1 , 0.0663 )-- ( 0.099 , 0.0678 )-- ( 0.098 , 0.0693 )-- ( 0.097 , 0.0706 )-- ( 0.096 , 0.072 )-- ( 0.095 , 0.0733 )-- ( 0.094 , 0.0746 )-- ( 0.093 , 0.0758 )-- ( 0.092 , 0.077 )-- ( 0.091 , 0.0782 )-- ( 0.09 , 0.0794 )-- ( 0.089 , 0.0805 )-- ( 0.088 , 0.0816 )-- ( 0.087 , 0.0826 )-- ( 0.086 , 0.0837 )-- ( 0.085 , 0.0847 )-- ( 0.084 , 0.0857 )-- ( 0.083 , 0.0867 )-- ( 0.082 , 0.0876 )-- ( 0.081 , 0.0885 )-- ( 0.08 , 0.0894 )-- ( 0.079 , 0.0903 )-- ( 0.078 , 0.0912 )-- ( 0.077 , 0.092 )-- ( 0.076 , 0.0929 )-- ( 0.075 , 0.0937 )-- ( 0.074 , 0.0945 )-- ( 0.073 , 0.0952 )-- ( 0.072 , 0.096 
)-- ( 0.071 , 0.0967 )-- ( 0.07 , 0.0975 )-- ( 0.069 , 0.0982 );

\draw [thick]( 0.635 , 0.4224 )-- ( 0.63 , 0.418 )-- ( 0.625 , 0.4139 )-- ( 0.62 , 0.41 )-- ( 0.615 , 0.4064 )-- ( 0.61 , 0.403 )-- ( 0.605 , 0.3998 )-- ( 0.6 , 0.3968 )-- ( 0.595 , 0.394 )-- ( 0.59 , 0.3914 )-- ( 0.585 , 0.389 )-- ( 0.58 , 0.3867 )-- ( 0.575 , 0.3846 )-- ( 0.57 , 0.3827 )-- ( 0.565 , 0.3809 )-- ( 0.56 , 0.3792 )-- ( 0.555 , 0.3777 )-- ( 0.55 , 0.3764 )-- ( 0.545 , 0.3751 )-- ( 0.54 , 0.374 )-- ( 0.535 , 0.3731 )-- ( 0.53 , 0.3723 )-- ( 0.525 , 0.3716 )-- ( 0.52 , 0.371 )-- ( 0.515 , 0.3706 )-- ( 0.51 , 0.3703 )-- ( 0.505 , 0.3701 )-- ( 0.5 , 0.37 )-- ( 0.495 , 0.3701 )-- ( 0.49 , 0.3703 )-- ( 0.485 , 0.3706 )-- ( 0.48 , 0.371 )-- ( 0.475 , 0.3716 )-- ( 0.47 , 0.3723 )-- ( 0.465 , 0.3731 )-- ( 0.46 , 0.374 )-- ( 0.455 , 0.3751 )-- ( 0.45 , 0.3764 )-- ( 0.445 , 0.3777 )-- ( 0.44 , 0.3792 )-- ( 0.435 , 0.3809 )-- ( 0.43 , 0.3827 )-- ( 0.425 , 0.3846 )-- ( 0.42 , 0.3867 )-- ( 0.415 , 0.389 )-- ( 0.41 , 0.3914 )-- ( 0.405 , 0.394 )-- ( 0.4 , 0.3968 )-- ( 0.395 , 0.3998 )-- ( 0.39 , 0.403 )-- ( 0.
385 , 0.4064 )-- ( 0.38 , 0.41 )-- ( 0.375 , 0.4139 )-- ( 0.37 , 0.418 );


\draw( 0.09 , 0.265141 )-- ( 0.1 , 0.261534 )-- ( 0.11 , 0.257488 )-- ( 0.12 , 0.252982 )-- ( 0.13 , 0.247992 )-- ( 0.14 , 0.242487 )-- ( 0.15 , 0.236432 )-- ( 0.16 , 0.229783 )-- ( 0.17 , 0.222486 )-- ( 0.18 , 0.214476 )-- ( 0.19 , 0.20567 );

\draw( 0.83 , 0.189737 )-- ( 0.84 , 0.203224 )-- ( 0.85 , 0.215407 )-- ( 0.86 , 0.226495 )-- ( 0.87 , 0.236643 )-- ( 0.88 , 0.245967 )-- ( 0.89 , 0.254558 )-- ( 0.9 , 0.262488 )-- ( 0.91 , 0.269815 );
\draw (0.52,0.32) node{\footnotesize{$\pi$-$2\alpha$}};

\draw (-.4,-0.8) node{$C_1$};
\draw (1.5,-0.8) node{$C_2$};
\draw (0.52,-0.72) node{$P$};
\draw (-.25,0.80) node{$R$};
\draw (1.25,0.80) node{$Q$};

\draw (0.40,2.15) node{$C_3$};
\draw[dotted](0.71,2.02)--(1.45,2.15)--(2.02,1.70)--(1.65,1.05)--(2.41,0.97)--(2.2,0.25)--(1.7,-0.30)--(1,0)--(0.50,-0.55)--(0,0)--(-0.0,0.75)--(0.5,1.30)--(0.71,2.02);
\draw[dotted](0.5,1.30)--(1.00,0.75)--(1.65,1.05);

\draw[dotted] (1.00,0.75)--(1,0);

\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{0.75}{\MyPic}
\scalebox{0.5}{\MyPic}  
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Using `tikz` scaling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyPic}[1]{%
\def\Scale{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\Scale, thick]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MinSize}{3*\Scale/2}
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, red] at (0.5,1.3) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, blue] at (0.0,0) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, brown] at (1,0) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, magenta] at (2.2,0.25) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, violet] at (1.65,1.05) {};
\node [draw, dotted, minimum size=\MinSize cm, circle, green] at (1.45,2.15) {};


\draw (0.7,1.30) node{$C$};
\draw (0.5,1.30) node{.};
\draw (-0.1,-0.10) node{$A$};
\draw (0.183,0.07) node{\footnotesize{$\alpha$}};
\draw (0.183,0.37) node{\footnotesize{$\gamma$}};
\draw (0.82,0.29) node{\footnotesize{$\beta$}};


\draw (0.5,0.70) node {$O$};

\draw (0,0) node{.};
\draw (1.1,0) node{$B$};
\draw (1,0) node{.};

\draw (0,0)--(0.50,0.57);
\draw (-0.002,-0.0)--(0.50,1.31);
\draw (1.005,0)--(0.50,1.31);


\draw (1,0)--(0.50,0.57);
\draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw [thick]( 0.12 , 0.0 )-- ( 0.119 , 0.0155 )-- ( 0.118 , 0.0218 )-- ( 0.117 , 0.0267 )-- ( 0.116 , 0.0307 )-- ( 0.115 , 0.0343 )-- ( 0.114 , 0.0375 )-- ( 0.113 , 0.0404 )-- ( 0.112 , 0.0431 )-- ( 0.111 , 0.0456 )-- ( 0.11 , 0.048 )-- ( 0.109 , 0.0502 )-- ( 0.108 , 0.0523 )-- ( 0.107 , 0.0543 )-- ( 0.106 , 0.0562 )-- ( 0.105 , 0.0581 )-- ( 0.104 , 0.0599 )-- ( 0.103 , 0.0616 )-- ( 0.102 , 0.0632 )-- ( 0.101 , 0.0648 )-- ( 0.1 , 0.0663 )-- ( 0.099 , 0.0678 )-- ( 0.098 , 0.0693 )-- ( 0.097 , 0.0706 )-- ( 0.096 , 0.072 )-- ( 0.095 , 0.0733 )-- ( 0.094 , 0.0746 )-- ( 0.093 , 0.0758 )-- ( 0.092 , 0.077 )-- ( 0.091 , 0.0782 )-- ( 0.09 , 0.0794 )-- ( 0.089 , 0.0805 )-- ( 0.088 , 0.0816 )-- ( 0.087 , 0.0826 )-- ( 0.086 , 0.0837 )-- ( 0.085 , 0.0847 )-- ( 0.084 , 0.0857 )-- ( 0.083 , 0.0867 )-- ( 0.082 , 0.0876 )-- ( 0.081 , 0.0885 )-- ( 0.08 , 0.0894 )-- ( 0.079 , 0.0903 )-- ( 0.078 , 0.0912 )-- ( 0.077 , 0.092 )-- ( 0.076 , 0.0929 )-- ( 0.075 , 0.0937 )-- ( 0.074 , 0.0945 )-- ( 0.073 , 0.0952 )-- ( 0.072 , 0.096 
)-- ( 0.071 , 0.0967 )-- ( 0.07 , 0.0975 )-- ( 0.069 , 0.0982 );

\draw [thick]( 0.635 , 0.4224 )-- ( 0.63 , 0.418 )-- ( 0.625 , 0.4139 )-- ( 0.62 , 0.41 )-- ( 0.615 , 0.4064 )-- ( 0.61 , 0.403 )-- ( 0.605 , 0.3998 )-- ( 0.6 , 0.3968 )-- ( 0.595 , 0.394 )-- ( 0.59 , 0.3914 )-- ( 0.585 , 0.389 )-- ( 0.58 , 0.3867 )-- ( 0.575 , 0.3846 )-- ( 0.57 , 0.3827 )-- ( 0.565 , 0.3809 )-- ( 0.56 , 0.3792 )-- ( 0.555 , 0.3777 )-- ( 0.55 , 0.3764 )-- ( 0.545 , 0.3751 )-- ( 0.54 , 0.374 )-- ( 0.535 , 0.3731 )-- ( 0.53 , 0.3723 )-- ( 0.525 , 0.3716 )-- ( 0.52 , 0.371 )-- ( 0.515 , 0.3706 )-- ( 0.51 , 0.3703 )-- ( 0.505 , 0.3701 )-- ( 0.5 , 0.37 )-- ( 0.495 , 0.3701 )-- ( 0.49 , 0.3703 )-- ( 0.485 , 0.3706 )-- ( 0.48 , 0.371 )-- ( 0.475 , 0.3716 )-- ( 0.47 , 0.3723 )-- ( 0.465 , 0.3731 )-- ( 0.46 , 0.374 )-- ( 0.455 , 0.3751 )-- ( 0.45 , 0.3764 )-- ( 0.445 , 0.3777 )-- ( 0.44 , 0.3792 )-- ( 0.435 , 0.3809 )-- ( 0.43 , 0.3827 )-- ( 0.425 , 0.3846 )-- ( 0.42 , 0.3867 )-- ( 0.415 , 0.389 )-- ( 0.41 , 0.3914 )-- ( 0.405 , 0.394 )-- ( 0.4 , 0.3968 )-- ( 0.395 , 0.3998 )-- ( 0.39 , 0.403 )-- ( 0.
385 , 0.4064 )-- ( 0.38 , 0.41 )-- ( 0.375 , 0.4139 )-- ( 0.37 , 0.418 );


\draw( 0.09 , 0.265141 )-- ( 0.1 , 0.261534 )-- ( 0.11 , 0.257488 )-- ( 0.12 , 0.252982 )-- ( 0.13 , 0.247992 )-- ( 0.14 , 0.242487 )-- ( 0.15 , 0.236432 )-- ( 0.16 , 0.229783 )-- ( 0.17 , 0.222486 )-- ( 0.18 , 0.214476 )-- ( 0.19 , 0.20567 );

\draw( 0.83 , 0.189737 )-- ( 0.84 , 0.203224 )-- ( 0.85 , 0.215407 )-- ( 0.86 , 0.226495 )-- ( 0.87 , 0.236643 )-- ( 0.88 , 0.245967 )-- ( 0.89 , 0.254558 )-- ( 0.9 , 0.262488 )-- ( 0.91 , 0.269815 );
\draw (0.52,0.32) node{\footnotesize{$\pi$-$2\alpha$}};

\draw (-.4,-0.8) node{$C_1$};
\draw (1.5,-0.8) node{$C_2$};
\draw (0.52,-0.72) node{$P$};
\draw (-.25,0.80) node{$R$};
\draw (1.25,0.80) node{$Q$};

\draw (0.40,2.15) node{$C_3$};
\draw[dotted](0.71,2.02)--(1.45,2.15)--(2.02,1.70)--(1.65,1.05)--(2.41,0.97)--(2.2,0.25)--(1.7,-0.30)--(1,0)--(0.50,-0.55)--(0,0)--(-0.0,0.75)--(0.5,1.30)--(0.71,2.02);
\draw[dotted](0.5,1.30)--(1.00,0.75)--(1.65,1.05);

\draw[dotted] (1.00,0.75)--(1,0);

\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\MyPic{1.5}
\MyPic{1.0}
\end{document}
```